# Unknown column in SQL syntax in a Python script

Tags: sql, python-3.x, mysql-connector

I have written a Python script where I update some lines of code in a MySQL database, and I got an error code like this:

```
raise errors.get_exception(packet)
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'dateatime' in 'field list'
```

the SQL syntax is:

```
cursor.execute("UPDATE db SET Status = status, Statusänderung_von = dateatime, Priorität = prioritaet WHERE Objekt_ID = %s" % (lineid))
```

I have tried many things but every time I have the same problem.
All variables like `prioritaet`, `dateatime` or `status` are set before.
could someone help please?

Comment: Add extra `%s` inside the sql query and declare the variables after `%`.. same as `lineid`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:

```
update db 
set Status = @status
    , Statusänderung_von = @dateatime
    , Priorität = @prioritaet
```

Here is a small [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2dd0e918befbf325fc24e4d62ab147cd) where you can see that without `@` you will get the error you have written in your question.

Comment: but dóes this work in a python script with mysql-connector?

Comment: Try it, and let us know. I have only added @ in front of your variable names. Let me know if it works.

Comment: WOW thank you a lot it works :D, but do you know why you have to add the '@' ?

Comment: I am happy it works. It is the way you use and declare variables in MySQL: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html

Comment: now i have the problem that i cant figure out how i can convert the python variables into the mysql @xxx Variable

Comment: Open a new question, try to be as clear as possible and give people some example data if possible. People eill help... but also, first try to find answer here on Stack Overflow...